# Having problems declaring arrays of arrays of object Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, 2d, slick2d

I have a problem using arrays of arrays of objects or simply arrays of objects and I'm pretty sure this isn't related to slick. Whenever the init method runs and get to the block part i'm getting a null pointer exception. I'm also sure that the problem is in me not declaring the Block objects properly. Please i really need some help on this.

```
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Stages extends BasicGameState {
    LevelInfo level = new LevelInfo(1);
    Block block[][];
    public Stages(int state) {

    }
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        level.init();
        for(int i = 0; i < 13;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 13;j++) {
                block[i][j] = new Block(level.type[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg,Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        for(int i = 0; i < 13;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 13;j++) {
                g.drawImage(block[i][j].image,j*60,i*60);
            }
        }
    }
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg,int delta) throws SlickException {

    }
    public int getID() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're never initializing `block` itself - it will always have a value of `null`. You need:

```
block = new Block[13][13];
```

in your `init` method, or in the constructor, or at the variable declaration.

A couple of other notes:

- You should almost certainly make your variables `private`
- You should probably avoid hard-coding the number 13 quite so often... could you have constants of `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` perhaps?
- It would be more idiomatic to declare the variable as:

  ```
  private Block[][] block;
  ```

  That keeps all the type information about the variable together. The "array part after the variable name" was really there to make existing C/C++ programmers happy when Java was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

You never instantiate your `2D` `block` array, resulting in the `NPE` then you attempt to assign the variable here

```
block[i][j] = new Block(level.type[i][j]);
```

You could declare your array thus:

```
private Block block[][] = new Block[13][13];
```

Comment: Thank you. You are the only one who answered me without condescending attitude.